# i have a positinal argument in __init__

Tags: python, tkinter, init

code is

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import simpledialog

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5050

class Client:

    def __init__(self,host,port):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        msg  = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)

        self.gui_done = False
        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")

        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')
    
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024)
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='diaabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.sock.close()
                break

Client=Client((HOST, PORT))
```

and the problem is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Aaryan\Comple Python Cource\GUI chat application\Client.py", line 90, in <module>
Client=Client((HOST, PORT))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'port'
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line:

```
Client=Client((HOST, PORT))
```

`(HOST, PORT)` is a tuple, so it's processed like a single argument. Pass 2 arguments instead (just remove redundant `()` ):

```
Client=Client(HOST, PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed a tuple to `Client()` which expects two arguments.

Use `client = Client(HOST, PORT)`.

Note that I have used `client` as the variable.  Don't use same name as the class.